# All your links are belong to us

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10795354/2123530

I stumbled upon this answer and, as one user correctly stated in the comments, the site which was linked to has been hacked.

For now I only HTML-commented the link, although I guess I could have  deleted it so that we could use the history to roll back if necessary.

In this case, what is the best thing to do?

- Monitor the link in the hope that the content gets restored, copy/paste it in the answer if it does and just give credit to the author?
- Just leave it be?
- Just warn the author of the answer in comments?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the user is still active. If you feel the answer is a complete answer without the link, you and the user who commented about the hack have done all you absolutely need to. (Really, you didn't even _need_ to edit, the answerer could have done so as well.) If the answerer feels they need to to anything more, or to quote the original post in the answer, they can. If the answer _does not_ stand without the link, the relevant parts of the original post _need_ to be brought over (properly quoted and attributed), provided they are compatible with the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: I let the user know his answer was brought up here, so he can come and see what advice comes up as well. (In case there's something he doesn't think of to handle the situation.)

Comment: The way to go [Archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622114654/http://vipinsahu.com/magento-mage-registry-key-_singletoncoreresource-already-exists)

Comment: Hmm. Looks like someone set them up the bomb.

Comment: This exploit is definitely a main screen turn on.

Comment: <self-note>You really only need a good title on meta to get noticed</self-note>

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Hey thanks for looking out. Yup the answer is complete anyway without the link. The link just explains it further, I believe.. To be honest I don't quite remember if I just put it there as some sort of attribution. I'll update the answer in a while to further explain the issue as well.

I believe you also did the right thing as well and as far as this meta question goes, the answer is yes.